# GoogleTest Framework seems not to work with Lambda functions (follow up)

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, lambda, googletest

This is a follow up to my last question:

[Google Test macros seem not to work with Lambda functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44459921/google-test-macros-seem-not-to-work-with-lambda-functions)

The solution mentioned in that case worked for that particular case, namely, the constructor of a template class inside the lambda could be wrapped in parantheses and the build would succeed. And I accepted that answer. But the question still remains, that the GoogleTest Framework seems not to work with Lambda functions. I see nothing on this in the documentation.

I did the following test,

```
TEST(errorhandlingInterpolator, NOTtoolargeInput) {
    ASSERT_NO_THROW(throw);
}
```

which would cause the test to fail. Good.

Then, I did this,

```
TEST(errorhandlingInterpolator, NOTtoolargeInput) {
        ASSERT_NO_THROW([](){throw;});
}
```

which would cause the test NOT to fail. Strange.

So, finally to be thorough about (something so trivial), I tested the following bit.

```
void dummy() { throw; }

TEST(errorhandlingInterpolator, NOTtoolargeInput) {
        ASSERT_NO_THROW(throw);
}
```

and the exception caused the test to fail. All good.

Which raised a flag in my head, do exceptions even work with lambda functions. I thought they were just like normal functions, except anonymous. Apparently they do. The following two questions talk about this.

[Can C++ lambda-expression throw?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22719066/can-c-lambda-expression-throw)

[throw an exception from a lambda expression, bad habit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37092596/throw-an-exception-from-a-lambda-expression-bad-habit)

So, it really does seem to boil down to the fact that the macros in google test framework do NOT work with lambda functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression in `ASSERT_NO_THROW([](){throw;})` does not execute an exception, it simply declares a lambda, which is then discarded, because it's not assigned to anything.

You want `ASSERT_NO_THROW([](){throw;}())`, which immediately attempts to execute the lambda.

Comment: I want to cry. I didn't know  my lambdas well enough and I went about yapping about something unrelated. :'(

Comment: yup! seems legit. That was the problem. Thanks!